# Java: How to generate an event from a socket readline()?

Tags: java, swing, sockets

I have messages (lines) coming in from a tcp socket, (the messages originating from a CAN gateway).  On selected messages, after selection and parsing, I want to update a swing GUI form (e.g. generated in Netbeans).

I read that the swing update must be driven from the event handler, and there are many examples, but they are based on button pushes, slider changes, etc., and not incoming socket data, (or serial ports).  It appears that I need to make the handling of a 'readline' of a socket generate an event, however I don't find examples and given that it has to be a common problem and maybe I'm on the wrong track and there might be simpler alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to run arbitrary code on the swing event thread. for example:

```
    String stuff = socket.readLine();
    if (myStuff(stuff)) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // do any updates to swing ui here
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: So, as I understand it, the code in "// do any updates..." is queued to run in the swing event dispatch thread.  Suppose the update sends a value to some chart, but there is a new socket line and resulting value before the chart completed the update.  Is it true that the close-following 'run' is in the EDT queue and that update will begin as soon as the 1st one completes?

Comment: @user3304253: yes, all events are queued